# Setting the time and displaying page content accordingly?

Tags: php, time

I am using the following code to display my page content at a certain desired time:

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jerusalem'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if ($dt > new DateTime("2015-09-05 01:15:00"))
 {
    include 'open.php';
}
    else {
        include 'closed.php';
    }

?>
```

The only problem I'm facing is when I upload the page on my real server (ipage).
Meaning , the time for example now is 2:49 AM, the code echoes the time correctly, BUT when I upload the page , it still shows the correct time , but does not display the page after 1:00 AM or 2:30 AM or 2:48 AM.

Things run fine on my local server , with at t -1 correction factor
for example if I want to open the page at 13:00 , I set the condition to be greater than 12:00.

What can be causing this and how can I settle this time difference issue once and for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot compare a object like DateTime object.

> $dt > new DateTime("2015-09-05 01:15:00")

which data are compared with each other?

compare with

- **$dt->diff();** `(not accurate enough)`
  (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)
  DateTime::diff -- DateTimeImmutable::diff -- DateTimeInterface::diff -- date_diff
  Returns the difference between two DateTime objects
- or **$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')**
  `2015-09-05 05:00:12 > 2015-09-05 01:15:00`

---

```
$dt  = new DateTime();
$dt2 = new DateTime("2015-09-05 01:15:00");
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jerusalem'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')." <br />\n";
echo $dt2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')." <br />\n";

if ($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') > $dt2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
{
    include 'open.php';
}
    else {
        include 'closed.php';
    }
```